# Make a new line inside a row html table

Tags: html, html-table

I am currently learning HTML table, I want to my HTML table looks like this [image: 1].
How do i create a table in html like that? What's wrong with my code? [Link to my full code](https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/xxgvNYa)

```html
<section class="container">
  <table class="order-table table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>john@john.com</td>
        <td>0001</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>jane@jane.com</td>
        <td>0002</td>
          <tr>
              <td><i class="mdi mdi-subdirectory-arrow-right"></i>Doe</td>
              <td>doe@doe.com</td>
              <td>0002a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><i class="mdi mdi-subdirectory-arrow-right"></i>Allan</td>
              <td>allan@allan.com</td>
              <td>0002b</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>smith@smith.com</td>
        <td>0003</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Remove the bottom border from the second and third rows.

Comment: By the way, it's not valid HTML to have a <tr> tag straight after a </td> tag.  You always need to close each row.  I guess you were thinking that somehow "nesting" the rows, with the arrows, inside the outer row would give you the result that you wanted, but that's not how it works.  In reality, when the browser sees a new <tr> it will effectively assume the previous row is closed anyway, so you're still just getting separate rows.  As @WaisKamal noted, you'll just need to change the visual display of those rows to appear how you want them to look.